# How to fix the schematics issue in angular-cli / unable to create new angular app

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I tried creating a new angular app using angular cli and it has been throwing the same error and not letting me create an app.

I have tried `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli` and installed it again 
using `npm install -g @angular/cli`

I have also tried to use `npm cache clean` and  `npm cache verify` but they did not work as well.

I have checked and updated the node and npm to latest versions but it still throws the same error

```
$ ng new angular-table
Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"name":"angular-table"}
```

Errors:

```
Data path "" should have required property 'version'.
```

The expected result is it should create a new angular app but it is throwing the error mentioned above

Comment: Please edit question by adding your package version with logs of `ng --version`

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, it requires property `--version` to be specified. After the new update of the `Angular CLI`, you need to specify version type of the project want to work with.
Like,

```
ng new <<name of the project>> --version=<<your version>>
```

In your case,

```
ng new angular-table --version=<<your version>>
```

Comment: Thanks Abhinav, I tried defining the version and that was creating the new project but it was not creating the angular.json file.

Comment: What's your angular CLI version?

Comment: I actually had two different angular-cli versions on my system which was causing the error. I installed the latest version but there was a folder which had angular-cli 2.0.2 in the program files which was causing this issue. I deleted that folder and the issue is resolved now. Thank you for taking time to look into this Abhinav!

Answer (score 0):

I created the Angular app in another drive and it worked.

Comment: I think you should try to go into the explorer on your system and search '@angular' - it will show all the angular files available and you have to delete an older version of angular-cli due to which this issue is getting caused.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what went wrong, there was an instance of angular-cli version 2.0.2 in my program files. I went through all the angular files in my system and deleted the older version. 
The presence of two different versions was causing a confusion as to which version it should pick up dependencies from due to which angular.json file was not getting created.
After deleting the older version files from my system now its working completely fine.